# CSS - Keep rounded image with floating elements

Tags: css

I have a newsfeed on a site with (for each news item) a header image and beneath the image a title. I would like to show the newsfeed a bit different on mobile. On mobile I want to show the image on the left side in a circle and on the right next to it, I want to display the title.

This is what I have:

```
@media(max-width: 600 px) {
  .widget--newsfeed.content-block__thumbnail {
    border-radius: 50 %;
    float: left;
    width: 25 %;
    display: inline;
  }
  .widget--newsfeed.content-block__fields {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    width: 75 %;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

It does exactly what I want, the only problem is that the image isn't a circle anymore. Because of the 25% width-value (I presume) the circle looks more like an egg. For some reason I can't alter the height of the image. Interesting side note, I'm not able to change the html of the content, I can only add/alter CSS and classes.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Not sure what `.widget--newsfeed.content - block__thumbnail` is supposed to be, but that’s not a valid CSS selector to begin with. And `max - width: 600 px` in your media query condition is also not correct.

Comment: These are the classes I created linked to the newsfeed. It's how the CMS works. Also, there went something wrong with the copy pasting of the code, because in my copy the max-width for example is shown correctly, sorry for that. Anyway, is there something I can add or adjust in order to solve the image problem?

Answer (score -1):

Give  Css direct to its child image. Please see the example in snippet.

```css
.round{ border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;}
    
    .round img {
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="round">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSyaALow02D9x21PCO5Z6Ewct0FdLtUYyB9Q_ECFyeL5hpU6pvg"/>
</div>
```